WHERE tomado como un string literal
tengo un detalle con una consulta MySQL intento actualizar una tabla, pero al momento de querer hacer la consulta la clausala WHERE me lo toma como un string literal y no como una clausula. aqui paso mi codigo,
if(isset($_POST['actualizar'])){
    $id_task= $_POST['id'];
    $title_task= $_POST['title_task'];
    $description_task= $_POST['description_task'];
    //WHERE (id_task='" .$_GET['id']. "') 
    //, id_task='" .$id_task. "'
    $updateDataQuery= "UPDATE task SET title_task='" .$title_task. "' , 
    
                                       description_task='" .$description_task. "'
                                        
                                       WHERE id_task='" .$_POST['id']. "' ";

    $updateData= mysqli_query($connect, $updateDataQuery);
    
    }

podrian regalarme alguna sugerencia?.

No me voy a meter en la forma en como operas con la DB, pero el error viene por no hacer las cosas bien desde el principio. Debes aprender a debuggear tu código de manera simple.
Acá van dos formas de hacerlo.
Primero es ver el resultado en pantalla de tu código y obviamente que ese resultado sirva en tu DBM (Database Manager, PHPmyAdmin, Navicat...)
$id_task= 33;
$title_task= 'title_task';
$description_task= 'description_task';
//WHERE (id_task='" .$_GET['id']. "')
//, id_task='" .$id_task. "'
echo $updateDataQuery = "UPDATE task SET
    title_task = $title_task ,
    description_task = $description_task ,
    WHERE id_task = $id_task
";

Resultado en pantalla

UPDATE task SET title_task = title_task , description_task = description_task , WHERE id_task = 33

Logras notar algo que está de más ahí?? Si exacto, esa coma antes del WHERE no debe estar ahí.
Otra cosa, porqué usas comillas dobles y simples concatenadas en una sentencia SQL?
La forma correcta es usar comillas dobles para todo el query y dentro usar comillas simples para algo puntual y las variables las escribes como tal.
$id = 33;
echo $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE description = 'Hola Mundo' AND id = $id ";
// Resultado 
// SELECT * FROM table WHERE description = 'Hola Mundo' AND id = 33

Por ultimo y lo que yo creo más optimo, es hacer primero el query en el DBM con datos de prueba y luego pasarlo a PHP
SELECT * FROM table WHERE description = 'Hola Mundo' AND id = 33

Y en PHP hacer solo el reemplazo
$id = 33;
$desccription = 'Hola Mundo';
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE description = $description AND id = $id ";
// Resultado 
// SELECT * FROM table WHERE description = 'Hola Mundo' AND id = 33


muchas gracias amigo tomare cartas en el asunto.

Te recomiendo usar una consulta preparada en vez de concatenar el SQL con las variables. Todavía usas mysqli en el estilo procedural en vez del estilo orientado al objeto, pero ese estilo viejo también permite preparar consultas.
if(isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
  $id_task = $_POST['id'];
  $title_task = $_POST['title_task'];
  $description_task = $_POST['description_task'];

  $updateDataQuery = "UPDATE task SET title_task = ?, description_task = ? WHERE id_task = ?";

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, updateDataQuery);
  if ($stmt === false) {
    die(mysqli_error($connect));
  }

  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $title_task, $description_task, $id_task);

  $status = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  if ($status === false) {
    die(mysqli_error($connect));
  }
}

No tengo mucha experiencia con PHP y mysqli. Así puede ser que mi código requiere revisión :-)

tienes razon amigo voy a cambiar la forma en la que escribo mis consultas.

el problema estaba en la forma de envio y comillas ya quedo.
include("connect.php");

if( isset($_POST['actualizar']) ) {

    $id_task = $_POST['id_task'];
    $title_task = $_POST['title_task'];
    $description_task = $_POST['description_task'];

    $update = "UPDATE usersx SET title_task = '$title_task' , description_task = '$description_task' WHERE id_task = '$id_task' " ;
    $send_update= mysqli_query($conn, $update);

    if($send_update){
        header("location: read.php");
    }else{
        echo "error";
        }


}



Y esto es una respuesta???
